# Exclude the output from ssh and only log the error if found

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, quoting

```
typeset -f | sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@${IPADDRESS} "
  $(cat);
  IFERROR=$(checkscript);
  echo "$IFERROR"" > ${SSHTEMPFILE} 2>&1
```

This line...I can't exclude the "user authorized" message from the ssh...IFERROR returns the values I need to track, but also, the "!!! AUTHORIZED USE ONLY !!!" horrible message from the ssh...
Already tried something like this, but its not working:

```
typeset -f | sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@${IPADDRESS} "
  $(cat);
  IFERROR=$(checkscript);
  echo "$IFERROR"" | grep -v "AUTHORIZED"  > ${SSHTEMPFILE} 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

The message you try to exclude is likely a ssh banner. This one is displayed on `stderr`, that's why the `grep -v` doesn't work in your script.

Just try to redirect `stderr` to `stdin` **before** the `grep`. It should work.
I don't really understand your command, but it would look like this:

```
typeset -f | sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@${IPADDRESS} "$(cat); IFERROR=$(checkscript); echo "$IFERROR"" 2>&1 | grep -v "AUTHORIZED" > ${SSHTEMPFILE}
```

PS: What's the purpose of `$(cat)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but there's at least one obvious mistake in your script. You have

```
ssh "$(cat); …"$IFERROR"" | …
```

The fragment `$IFERROR` is not inside quotes, it is expanded by the local shell in order to build the SSH command that is executed. You want to execute `echo "$IFERROR"` on the remote side, so you need to quote the `$` to prevent it from being expanded locally:

```
typeset -f | sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@${IPADDRESS} "
  $(cat);
  IFERROR=$(checkscript);
  echo \"\$IFERROR\"" > ${SSHTEMPFILE} 2>&1
```

The `checkscript` command is also executed locally. If you meant for it to be executed remotely, change `IFERROR=$(checkscript)` to `IFERROR=\$(checkscript)`.

You don't need to store the output of `checkscript` in a variable. You can, but it made your life more complicated for no benefit. Just get its output directly.

```
typeset -f |
sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@${IPADDRESS} "$(cat); checkscript" > ${SSHTEMPFILE} 2>&1
```